# Displaying a table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hey all I am stuck on displaying a table on my webapge using php. Everytime I try something new, I seem to get a new error. Im really stuck here I am trying to display a table Client which has Columns ID,Name,Phone,Email. I can't seem to get the data into the table. Can anyone help using mysqli?

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'form.php';


echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th><th>Email</th></tr>";

if($result = $mysqli_query("SELECT * from Client")){
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     echo "<tr><td>";
     echo $row["ID"];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row["name"];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row["email"];
     echo "</td><td><a href=delclient.php?id=";
     echo $row["id"];
     echo ">DEL</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
     echo "<a href=addclient.php?id=";
     echo $row["id"];
     echo ">EDIT</a>";

     echo "</td></tr>";
  }
 echo "</table>";    

 }
?>
```

Comment: `$mysqli_query` should be `mysqli_query`. Please describe the problem or error in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$mysqli_query`, it should be `mysqli_query`:

```
if($result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Client")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tristan points out, your call `$mysqli_query()` is wrong; it should be either

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * from Client")
```

or

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from Client")
```

where `$conn` is the database connection created in `connect.php`. Given your use of object syntax to reference the result fields, I suspect the first of the above to be the correct one.